# awk print lines with n columns and ignore last line

Tags: bash, awk

I am trying to get better at awk and use it for some formatting of a csv file which has multiple header rows with the actual reporting beginning after `n` lines. The report also has a footer which needs to be discarded. Following is my attempt at combining the conditions to produce a clean report

```
  awk -F, '{NF==25} END {NR>2 {print l} {l=$0}}' 6999_RACV_Master_Conversion_Report_csv_20171005_114903_618978908.csv > 6999_RACV_Master_Conversion_Report_csv_20171005_114903_618978908_formatted.csv
```

With above I am able to get rid of the footer but the headers exist. Here is hte sample data

```
    Date/Time Generated,10/5/17 11:46 AM
    Report Time Zone,Australia/Sydney
    Account ID,6999
    Date Range,9/1/17 - 9/30/17
    Floodlight Configuration,Equals:6017727
    Activity,Equals:RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration (4136140)
    Activity,Equals:RACV_INT_MMO_Sales (4135439)
    Activity,Equals:RACV_PARTNER_TMNFATravel_Consideration (4136141)
    Activity,Equals:RACV_PARTNER_TMNFATravel_Sales (4136142)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - C&E Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.17 (10581787)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Commercial Insurance Display FY17 (11180171)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - EHA Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10559465)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - EHA Online Video FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10604948)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - EHA The Block 2017 - Digital (20185347)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - ERA Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10548416)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - ERA Online Video FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10554300)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10647172)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Finance Caravan Loans Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10580422)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Finance Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10598350)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Home Security Social FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10701389)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Mobile Tyres FY18 - NEW 01.07.17 (20089973)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Energy Comapre FY18 (Child) (20214029)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV Home Products & Services (20321908)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Personal Insurance Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10605443)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Personal Insurance Online Video  FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10730454)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Renters Insurance FY1718 (20192006)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Resorts Display FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10512704)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Resorts Online Video FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16 (10591278)
    Campaign,Equals:RACV - Travel Insurance FY17 Display - NEW - 16.11.16 (10613550)
    MRC Accredited Metrics,None

    Report Fields
    Date,Activity,Activity ID,Campaign,Campaign ID,Site (DCM),Placement,Creative,Impression Count,IsPartnerName (string),OrderType (string),OrderProd (string),OrderName (string),OrderID (string),OrderRevenue (string),OrderPAX (string),OrderQ
    uantity (string),OrderStep (string),OrderDateFrom (string),OrderDateTill (string),Conversion URL,Click-through Conversions,View-through Conversions,Total Conversions,Total Revenue
    2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
    -banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
    ent=;ord=1256092675587.8044;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte/!ut/p/b1/hY3JDoJAEES_iHQPmAGOIATDKg4izIXgEgRZggskfL3oHa1bJa9eAYeUSBSpLBMKCfA2H8oif5Zdm9efzmkmIlWZYxFUQrZGTY-IE7AAUSQzkM4ALkTDf3sbeFF3x_nqAPwL_3D5m665QDpj8
    qLTkyCCBFcZq5SudwfdnUwprsbxMTHVrkLlNZ2I7zq9Z-DVi9Rke453e13T7oLhmtDwWrkJVvEG7M0tJA!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_2069SKG108QSC0ABT1KOSO00M3/act/id=0/p=backJspName=QFBuote_About_You/p=javax.portlet.action=backActionSubmit/36551187388
    3/-/,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
    2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
    -banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
    ent=;ord=1936578182591.1943;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
    2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
    -banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
    ent=;ord=5398916632833.284;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte/!ut/p/b1/hY3JDoJAEES_iHQPmAGOIATDKg4izIXgEgRZggskfL3oHa1bJa9eAYeUSBSpLBMKCfA2H8oif5Zdm9efzmkmIlWZYxFUQrZGTY-IE7AAUSQzkM4ALkTDf3sbeFF3x_nqAPwL_3D5m665QDpj8q
    LTkyCCBFcZq5SudwfdnUwprsbxMTHVrkLlNZ2I7zq9Z-DVi9Rke453e13T7oLhmtDwWrkJVvEG7M0tJA!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_2069SKG108QSC0ABT1KOSO00M3/act/id=0/p=backJspName=QFBuote_About_You/p=javax.portlet.action=backActionSubmit/365511963564
    /-/,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
Grand Total:,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,---,810.00,39373.00,40183,0.000000000
```

Expected output:-

```
Date,Activity,Activity ID,Campaign,Campaign ID,Site (DCM),Placement,Creative,Impression Count,IsPartnerName (string),OrderType (string),OrderProd (string),OrderName (string),OrderID (string),OrderRevenue (string),OrderPAX (string),OrderQ
uantity (string),OrderStep (string),OrderDateFrom (string),OrderDateTill (string),Conversion URL,Click-through Conversions,View-through Conversions,Total Conversions,Total Revenue
2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
-banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
ent=;ord=1256092675587.8044;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte/!ut/p/b1/hY3JDoJAEES_iHQPmAGOIATDKg4izIXgEgRZggskfL3oHa1bJa9eAYeUSBSpLBMKCfA2H8oif5Zdm9efzmkmIlWZYxFUQrZGTY-IE7AAUSQzkM4ALkTDf3sbeFF3x_nqAPwL_3D5m665QDpj8
qLTkyCCBFcZq5SudwfdnUwprsbxMTHVrkLlNZ2I7zq9Z-DVi9Rke453e13T7oLhmtDwWrkJVvEG7M0tJA!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_2069SKG108QSC0ABT1KOSO00M3/act/id=0/p=backJspName=QFBuote_About_You/p=javax.portlet.action=backActionSubmit/36551187388
3/-/,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
-banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
ent=;ord=1936578182591.1943;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
2017-09-01,RACV_INT_MMO_Consideration,4136140,RACV - Business Loans Digital FY17 - NEW - 16.11.16,10647172,Accuen Australia,Business Loans_OMDP_DBM_Custom Affinity_Leaderboard_728x90_Desktop_P25-54_Performance_,RAC18580-Car-Loans-Digital
-banners-728-x-90,12,,,,Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1,,,,,Step-1,,,;src=6017727;type=racv-0;cat=racv_000;u7=;u8=;u9=;u10=;u11=;u12=;u13=Car-Insurance-quote-Step-1;u16=;u17=;u18=Step-1;u20=;u21=;dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;tag_for_child_directed_treatm
ent=;ord=5398916632833.284;~oref=https://mymembership.racv.com.au/wps/portal/mqte/!ut/p/b1/hY3JDoJAEES_iHQPmAGOIATDKg4izIXgEgRZggskfL3oHa1bJa9eAYeUSBSpLBMKCfA2H8oif5Zdm9efzmkmIlWZYxFUQrZGTY-IE7AAUSQzkM4ALkTDf3sbeFF3x_nqAPwL_3D5m665QDpj8q
LTkyCCBFcZq5SudwfdnUwprsbxMTHVrkLlNZ2I7zq9Z-DVi9Rke453e13T7oLhmtDwWrkJVvEG7M0tJA!!/dl4/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_2069SKG108QSC0ABT1KOSO00M3/act/id=0/p=backJspName=QFBuote_About_You/p=javax.portlet.action=backActionSubmit/365511963564
/-/,0.00,1.00,1,0.000000000
```

Comment: Please show sample input and expected output

Comment: Apart from what Akshay requested to post sample data(which you should put in code tags into your post), one thing I noticed that in END block you condition NR>2 will not work properly for all the lines because END section of awk comes once it is done with reading all the lines of Input_file.

Comment: Thanks for adding sample Input, what is the expected output, please add that too in code tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For given input, below one should work

```
awk  'f{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"")}f && !/Grand/; /Report Fields/{f=1}' infile
```

OR even

```
awk  'f && sub(/^[ \t]+/,""); /Report Fields/{f=1}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `/Report Fields/{f=1}` if awk finds line with pattern, set variable `f=1`
- `f{sub(/^[ \t]+/,"")}` if variable `f` is set, suppress space tab chars at the beginning of line.
- `f && !/Grand/;` if variable `f` is set, and line doesn't contain `Grand` then print such line.
- `f && sub(/^[ \t]+/,"");` if variable `f` is set, `sub()` returns boolean true, then print such line/record (so that line with `Grand Total:` will be skipped, as line doesn't match `/^[ \t]+/`)

Answer (score 1):

Using awk you can start `print`ing from the record `NR`>*n* but you have to provide the number of records if you want to stop `print`ing after some certain record. Another way is to keep the last *n* records in the buffer (below just one record buffer `p` as in *previous*). But first some test file:

```
$ cat file
head1      # unwanted
head2      # wanted
record1    # wanted
record2    # wanted
footer     # unwanted
```

then the script with its output:

```
$ awk 'NR>2{print p}{p=$1}' file
head2
record1
record2
```

**Edit**:

With that particular data (with records split and all), use this:

```
$ awk 'NR>=34{print p}{p=$0}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another thought to use `sed`,

```
sed -n '/Report Fields/,$!b;//d;$!p' file
```

Brief explanation,

- `/Report Fields/,$ !b`: skip the script if the lines are not at the range of 
  "Report Fields" to the final line
- `//d`: delete the line contains "Report Fields"
- `$!p`: print the remaining lines except the last one

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shown us the sample data and sample expected output, so based on your statement and assumptions like your header is on very first line and your footer is on very last line of your Input_file following may help you in same then.
Let's say following is Input_file:

```
cat file_test
My header
bla bla bla bla data data data
bla bla bla bla
```

So following is the code by which it will skip 1st line and last line(header and footer respectively).

```
awk -v lines=$(wc -l < file_test) 'NR>1 && NR<lines' file_test
bla bla bla bla data data data
bla bla bla bla
```

***PS:*** If you have some other requirement then kindly post sample Input_file with expected output too in code tags in your post.

Comment: It's customary to comment when downvoting. (this is not the comment associated with the downvote :)

Comment: I think someone downvoted because you (we) answered to an unfinished question. I could also be related to your output not reflecting that the last record is not printed.